# AWS CF !If failes

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, devops

my AWS CF fails when condition meets.
meaning that when CreateProdResources is true im getting the following Error:

```
Value of property AlarmActions must be of type List of String
```

```
AlarmActions:
                - !Ref SparksTeamSNSTopic
                - !If
                    - CreateProdResources
                    - - !Ref SparksProdAlarmSNSTopic
                      - !ImportValue
                          'Fn::Sub': '${Environment}-BMCCriticalAlarmTopic'
                    - !Ref 'AWS::NoValue'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below template, I've also included 2 different methods of doing your !if condition.

From your code snippet above the issue I can see is that you are trying to include **2 topics** to a **single list item** using a condition, causing your error *AlarmActions must be of type List of String*. Therefore you need to split out your 2 topics to 2 list items as I have shown.

```
AlarmActions:
  - !Ref CloudtrailAlarmNotification
  - !If
    - CreateProdResources
    - Fn::ImportValue:
        !Sub 'RestAPI-${PartnerDataEndpointResource}-URLendpoint-${Stage}'
    - !Ref 'AWS::NoValue'
  - !If [CreateProdResources, !Ref SparksProdAlarmSNSTopic, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
```

Comment: thanks, already figured out that i need to split the if condition to 2.